# Custom Auto Increment field in Umbraco

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco

I have worked with my self programmed CMS but new on Umbraco. I am working on **Umbraco 4.7** with .net framework 4 and want to create a content structure somewhat like this

```
MaleModels
|--------------Model (Can be multiple)
                 |----------- Model Id (Problem) 
                 |----------- Name
                 |----------- DOB
                 |----------- etc...
```

I need to create node for each Model and want to assign a unique Model Id to each model but can't find any data type that can be used for Auto Increment field (As I do when programming custom .net code with SQL). I know that I can use @pageId, but I want Model Id to start from 100 and with single increment for each Model only.

Need Help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is that you could handle the Document.AfterPublish event in a custom library that could add the auto increment value to a "autoID" field after creation and save/publish it again.  You may need to keep a counter of the current increment id value (say in the "MaleModels" node above) so you don't have to query all of the Models each time to find the highest ID.

Here's a blog post about events in Umbraco that may help with the details: http://www.bo-mortensen.dk/2011/10/umbraco-more-event-goodness/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after some more analysis, I got an idea. Shouldn't I create another table **ModelInformation[ModelId PK (AutoIncrement), ModelNodeId (FK from cms_Content)]**, and as stated by you I can use Umbraco event model to perform this task. Is it the **cms_Content** table that stores nodeIds of Umbraco nodes. If it is then I can use Umbrao event model to get "created node Id" and store it in ModelInformation table. Next time whenever a Model node is encountered, I'll take its nodeId and find the corresponding ModelId from ModelInformation table.

Comment: Yes, you could certainly add another table and store it that way as well.  Would it be important to see that ID in the Umbraco Admin area?  You may want to create a simple UserControl DataType that displays the ID on the page in the admin area.

Comment: Yes, it will be good to show model Id in admin area, actually in a label. In fact, I have found a good project on [www.nibble.com](http://www.nibble.be/?p=24), Do you also have something to share?

Comment: This umbraco.tv video is a good tutorial: http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/developing-with-umbraco/data-editors/creating-a-custom-datatype-using-the-usercontrol-wrapper

Comment: Tim's blog a nibble is a great resource as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing link, I think you should post some free link for me and may be for future visitors, as the **link above requires an Umbraco premium subscription.**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create "**Custom User Control**" which has database and you can create first column as Auto-incremental and second column as NodeId, once you done that please add that into the database on `Page_Load()` event make sure you check if NodeId exist then don't insert record.

Now create as DataType in Umbraco then use as property, User Control will get Auto-incremental number when you create node that user control will insert record with NodeId and will generate Auto-incremental and display into the `page_load()` into `<asp:Label>`,

It will heat every time page load so what you can do is that you will need to check every time into you database is NodeId exist or not if it exist then don't insert otherwise insert into the database that way you can create your auto-incremental,

You need to bare in mind that will be heating every-time database just make sure with performance wise you need to look into it.

if you have further question please do let me know.

Thanks

Ankur